# Objective C, dealing with crash report when it is not involved my app in stack trace

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

There are many ways for application to catch a crash. In most kinds of them there is much enough that info which is provided by IDE. (Xcode & iOS/OS X development)
But there are some crash reports which provide us the crashed thread and it’s stack trace (as usual) but no one frame from it is pointed to any call from our application! There are involved native libraries there.

Could anybody share his/her own experience of fixing such kinds of bugs with existing crash reports?

Many thanks in advance!

UPD:
I'm familiar with such docs as: [Crash Report (TN2123)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html), looked through [function calling conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/140-x86-64_Function_Calling_Conventions/x86_64.html), started [Mac OS X Debugging Magic (TN2124)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html).
But didn't succeed yet.
UPD2, stack trace:

```
Process:               My Application [5708]
Path:                  /Applications/My Application.app/Contents/MacOS/My Application
Identifier:            com.MyApplication
Version:               1.0 (0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           My Application [5708]
User ID:               10001

Date/Time:             2015-05-05 18:30:02.782 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        FE6D3DC3-9F32-246F-B1FD-5884D8CABA62

Sleep/Wake UUID:       7B4B18F9-E17D-48CA-AB36-0C75F236A14F

Time Awake Since Boot: 9000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.videotoolbox.preparationQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000011ccce000

VM Regions Near 0x11ccce000:
    IOKit                  000000011cc5a000-000000011ccce000 [  464K] rw-/rw- SM=SHM
-->
    IOKit                  000000011d04f000-000000011d0fd000 [  696K] rw-/rw- SM=SHM

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1bfb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1befdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1be838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c28a43f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c28a1ba ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c289ffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84b0a6d1 _DPSNextEvent + 964
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84b09e80 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84afde23 -[NSApplication run] + 594
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84ae92d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
12  com.MyApplication               0x0000000104eac864 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6722e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92e85a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.videotoolbox.preparationQueue
0   com.apple.VideoToolbox          0x00007fff92ee10e5 0x7fff92eac000 + 217317
1   com.apple.VideoToolbox          0x00007fff92ec324b VTPixelTransferSessionTransferImage + 13362
2   com.apple.VideoToolbox          0x00007fff92eb40e7 0x7fff92eac000 + 32999
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92e82c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92e86365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92e87ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92e856b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff92e93fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc6cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1bfb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1befdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1be838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c6d7a7 _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1bfb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1befdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1be838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8465bd20 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff842ecb7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e663f6 __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d424ff8 CVDisplayLink::waitUntil(unsigned long long) + 240
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d4244b3 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 511
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d42429b startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1bfb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1befdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1be838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a274ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d39b82e DeckLinkDeviceNotificationControlMac::MessageLoop() + 176
7   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d39b3ad DeviceNotificationController::MessageLoopFunc(void*) + 15
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8fb4b23a io_connect_method + 381
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8faef532 IOConnectCallScalarMethod + 111
4   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3f469f Nativeproxy::writeScalarReadScalar(int, unsigned long long const*, unsigned int, unsigned long long*, unsigned int) + 39
5   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3edc53 WaitForNotificationEvents + 94
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d368db8 CDeckLinkNotification::run() + 102
7   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d368e7a thread_entry(void*) + 9
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1bfb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1befdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1be838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a274ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d39b82e DeckLinkDeviceNotificationControlMac::MessageLoop() + 176
7   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d39b3ad DeviceNotificationController::MessageLoopFunc(void*) + 15
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8fb4b23a io_connect_method + 381
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8faef532 IOConnectCallScalarMethod + 111
4   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3f469f Nativeproxy::writeScalarReadScalar(int, unsigned long long const*, unsigned int, unsigned long long*, unsigned int) + 39
5   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3edc53 WaitForNotificationEvents + 94
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d368db8 CDeckLinkNotification::run() + 102
7   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d368e7a thread_entry(void*) + 9
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8fb4b23a io_connect_method + 381
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8faef532 IOConnectCallScalarMethod + 111
4   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3f469f Nativeproxy::writeScalarReadScalar(int, unsigned long long const*, unsigned int, unsigned long long*, unsigned int) + 39
5   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3edc53 WaitForNotificationEvents + 94
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d38ab81 CDeckLinkOutput::DriverNotificationThread() + 119
7   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3879bd CDeckLinkOutput::DriverNotificationThreadFunction(void*) + 9
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8fb4b23a io_connect_method + 381
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8faef532 IOConnectCallScalarMethod + 111
4   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3ee507 WaitForVideoOutputPreviewEvent + 51
5   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d38a427 CDeckLinkOutput::VideoPreviewThread(PreviewThreadArgs*) + 103
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d3882e0 CDeckLinkOutput::VideoPreviewThreadFunction(void*) + 18
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1bfb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1befdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a1be838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a274ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.blackmagic-design.desktopvideo.DeckLinkAPI  0x000000010d37263f CDeckLink::DriverNotificationThreadFunction(void*) + 89
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: com.apple.coremedia.mediaprocessor.videocompression
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66162 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   com.apple.VideoToolbox          0x00007fff92eb087b VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame + 378
2   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bc4f12e 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 2162990
3   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bc26cd9 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1998041
4   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bc2693f 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1997119
5   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bc1b367 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1950567
6   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a217b5 figThreadMain + 417
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: com.apple.coremedia.mediaprocessor.audiocompression
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a20d31 WaitOnCondition + 11
2   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a20b3e FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bc1b343 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1950531
4   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a217b5 figThreadMain + 417
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6152e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e6069f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8fb4b23a io_connect_method + 381
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff8faef532 IOConnectCallScalarMethod + 111
4   com.apple.IOAccelerator         0x00007fff8ca1d449 IOAccelContextFinishFenceEvent + 42
5   com.apple.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsVADriver  0x000000010ecc2732 0x10ecb0000 + 75570
6   com.apple.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsVADriver  0x000000010ecdd6ca 0x10ecb0000 + 186058
7   com.apple.AppleGVAFramework     0x000000010e8ba4ab 0x10e81d000 + 644267
8   com.apple.AppleGVAFramework     0x000000010e8ba150 0x10e81d000 + 643408
9   com.apple.AppleGVAFramework     0x000000010e8baf74 0x10e81d000 + 647028
10  com.apple.AppleGVAFramework     0x000000010e8bbe2b 0x10e81d000 + 650795
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: com.apple.coremedia.formatwriter.qtmovie
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e67636 pwrite + 10
1   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a12363 FigFileByteStreamWrite + 60
2   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a11265 CMByteStreamWriteBlockBuffer + 320
3   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bbea72c 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1750828
4   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bbe5e6c 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1732204
5   com.apple.MediaToolbox          0x00007fff8bbe3726 0x7fff8ba3f000 + 1722150
6   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff90a217b5 figThreadMain + 417
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbcc279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87e66946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8cbca4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 23:

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000010  rbx: 0x00000000000003c0  rcx: 0x000000011c6afa80  rdx: 0x000000011c99dc00
  rdi: 0x00000000000002c0  rsi: 0x000000000000007b  rbp: 0x00000001051f3a60  rsp: 0x00000001051f3940
   r8: 0x0000000000000438   r9: 0x000000011c88fc00  r10: 0x0000000000000f00  r11: 0x0000000000000780
  r12: 0x000000011c676000  r13: 0x000000011cccd500  r14: 0x000000011c871000  r15: 0x000000011c97f000
  rip: 0x00007fff92ee10e5  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000011ccce000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:...
```

I noticed that address in `Exception Code` is equal to address in `cr2` register but not in `rip` as is written in tech notes.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lldb` or `gdb` to debug the code from the `Xcode's` debug console. At the time of crash these commands could be useful to get info about the state of your objects at runtime to proceed towards the root cause of the issue. For the list of commands which you can use refer http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

or

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=6

Also you can enable `Zombie` for getting more info related to crash

`NSZombie` is a `Cocoa` trick that turns any object going to be `deallocated` into a `NSZombie` instance. You are going to crash anyway, but instead of `Xcode` just complaining that you tried to access the wrong memory address, you get something a bit better like this:

```
2011-02-25 01:27:57.063 WordPress[10496:207] *** -[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xcf1b0c0
```

Not much, but at least you know that the guilty object was a string.

For more info related to `Zombie` refer https://cocoaforbreakfast.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/exc_bad_access-a-zombie-nightmare/

Comment: That's cool. But. As You have written `...at runtime`. And there is no availability to reproduce it in Xcode or Instruments or debug it using lldb. Just I'm not able to catch that crash. But want to find out the reason.

Comment: @MixeiLysenko, yes you can, suppose you set a breakpoint at app did finish launching with option at run time, your code control will stop at that instance, now open the debug console with partition view, at left side you will see self and at right side lldb

Comment: @MixeiLysenko, on debug area after lldb try executing 'lldb po self'

Comment: @MixeiLysenko you will get info about app delegate, similarly you can debug other objects, po self means print object self and self at present is app delegate's reference.

Comment: I know what `po self` means. I didn't understand do You suppose to set a breakpoint at `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`?

Comment: @MixeiLysenko, i was just informing you about a usage of po and nothing else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79419/discussion-between-mixei-lysenko-and-sanjay-mohnani).